# Unable to start Azure VM after size change

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-virtual-machine, disk

I have Azure VM (Windows Server 2012R2 with SQL Server).

Since I was changed the size I cannot start the VM, When I'm trying to start I got the following failed error:

> Provisioning state Provisioning failed. One or more errors occurred while preparing VM disks. See disk instance view for details.. DiskProcessingError
>
> DISKS
>   MyVM_OsDisk_1_47aaea403b8948fb8d0e3ba0e81e2fas Provisioning failed. Requested operation cannot be performed because storage account type 'Premium_LRS' is not supported for VM size 'Standard_D2_v3'.. VMSizeDoesntSupportPremiumStorage
>
> MyVM_disk2_ccc04be996a5471688d357bf6f955fab Provisioning failed. Requested operation cannot be performed because storage account type 'Premium_LRS' is not supported for VM size 'Standard_D2_v3'.. VMSizeDoesntSupportPremiumStorage

What Is the problem and how can I solve it please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error details shows, this is because Premium disk is not supported for D2_V3 VM Size.

Solution :

1. If you want to use SSD premium Disk for your VM , you can [**Resize your VM size**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/resize-vm) to DS-series, DSv2-series, GS-series, Ls-series, and Fs-series VMs.
2. If you don't mind using Standard HDD disk, but want to use D2_V3 VMsize. You can **Change the Disk type to Standard** (If your disks are managed).

Deallocate your VM > Disk > Choose the disk  > Change the Account type to standard > save

[image]

Additional, I assume that your disks are managed. If not,  you'd better resize your VM rather than change back to standard disk.